# How to remove a project from the list on BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

I'd like to declutter the list of projects and repositories that shows up on my account's page on BitBucket website. There are quite a few projects/repos I was invited to but I don't own. How can I remove them from my list?

Please note the answers like this one:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-delete-a-project-not-just-a-repository-in-BitBucket/qaq-p/901241

doesn't work. I can't access the settings of projects that are not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave someone's workspace from here https://bitbucket.org/account/workspaces

And this operation will remove all repos from this workspace